# how to make section of a html page change everytime the page loads

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a way to change a section of html every time the page loads.

example.

I have a three links:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/test1">google test one</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com/test2">google test two</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com/test3">google test three</a>
```

every time someone loads the page the links will change.

Page version 1:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black"><td>  <a href="http://www.google.com/test1">google test one</a></td></table>
```

page version 2:

```
  <table style="border: 1px solid black"><td>  <a href="http://www.google.com/test2">google test two</a></td></table>
```

page version 3:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black"><td>  <a href="http://www.google.com/test3">google test three</a></td></table>
```

Is there any way to do this?
Maybe javascript?
I only know html, so I'm not very good at this sort of thing.
I have tried searching on google but i don't know what to search for.

Comment: IF you are willing to Change the Page Dynamically. You defintely need Javascript. You may also wanna learn JQuery, because its simpler to learn and use.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to achieve what you want, bearing in mind that this kind of dynamic behaviour requires either a client-side ([javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)) or server-side ([ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), [php](/questions/tagged/php), etc) solution, is the following approach:

```
var linksList = [
    'http://google.com/',
    'http://stackoverflow.com/',
    'http://slashdot.org/'
    ],
    el = document.getElementById('demo'),
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * linksList.length);

el.href = linksList[randomNumber];
el.textContent = linksList[randomNumber];
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kgGMh/).

Slightly more complex is the following (which does the same thing, but uses an array of objects to offer more configurable options to each of the links):

```
var linksList = [{
    'url': 'http://google.com/',
        'text': 'Google.com'
}, {
    'url': 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
        'text': 'Programming Q&A'
}, {
    'url': 'http://slashdot.org/',
        'text': 'Slashdot: News for Nerds'
}],
    el = document.getElementById('demo'),
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * linksList.length);

el.href = linksList[randomNumber].url;
el.textContent = linksList[randomNumber].text;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kgGMh/1/).

And a slightly *more* complex (though it becomes more maintainable at this point) approach is to start using functions which can be called on multiple items:

```
function randomiseLinks(el, list) {
    if (!el || !list) {
        return false;
    } else {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
        el.href = list[randomNumber].url;
        el.textContent = list[randomNumber].text;
    }
}

var linksList = [{
    'url': 'http://google.com/',
        'text': 'Google.com'
}, {
    'url': 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
        'text': 'Programming Q&A'
}, {
    'url': 'http://slashdot.org/',
        'text': 'Slashdot: News for Nerds'
}],
    links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    randomiseLinks(links[i], linksList);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kgGMh/3/).

The following approach has the benefits of the above functional approach, but as it extends the `Object` prototype it means it can be called directly on an element, or nodeList, returned by `document.getElementById()` or `document.getElementsByTagName()` (among others):

```
Object.prototype.randomiseLinks = function (list) {
    var test = this.length,
        that = test ? [] : [this],
        randomNumber;
    if (test){
        for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++){
            that[i] = this[i];
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0, len = that.length; i < len; i++){
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
        that[i].href = list[randomNumber].url;
        that[i].textContent = list[randomNumber].text;
    }
    return this;
};

var linksList = [{
    'url': 'http://google.com/',
    'text': 'Google.com'
}, {
    'url': 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
    'text': 'Programming Q&A'
}, {
    'url': 'http://slashdot.org/',
    'text': 'Slashdot: News for Nerds'
}];
```

Can be called as follows:

[`document.getElementById('test').randomiseLinks(linksList);`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kgGMh/8/)

Or:

[`document.getElementsByTagName('a').randomiseLinks(linksList);`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kgGMh/7/)

Comment: How would I do this with a block of html. eg. If I wanted to change some text, instead of links.

Comment: In much the same way, just change the appropriate properties. What particular elements are you wanting to change in what way?